# How to prevent duplicate messages in Kafka and improve delivery time

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

we are running Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS  with 32GB of RAM and about a terabyte of harddrive space: We are running kafka_2.13-3.2.1
All we added to the standard default configuration is

```
#allow us to delete Kafka topics
delete.topic.enable = true

### Change for large message
max.request.size=30728640
message.max.bytes=30728640
max.partition.fetch.bytes=30728640
```

We have two problems:

1. It takes about 5 - 10 minutes for the consumer to read data from the queue.
2. We are getting duplicate messages from the queue.

Also, I didn't get any errors on the console log.

Any suggestions on how to solve the problem appreciated.

Comment: Nothing prevents duplicate messages, and there's no guarantee of delivery time...

Comment: Thanks for your response @OneCricketeer but I didn't get your point. my question is how to prevent duplicate messages and consistent delivery time?

Comment: For your second query , it is not possible that kafka will give out duplicates unless the producer writing to topic sends duplicates, You can check that..

Comment: My point is that you can't. You can use transactions, or an external database for the same, to _reduce chances of duplicates_ **by the producer**, or ensure durable writes, but it's not guaranteed to prevent duplicate processing _by the consumer_, and that'll certainly increase delivery times. As mentioned by Vishal, it's up to your code to not call producer send action for same data more than once